# copying a short int to a char array

Tags: c++, c, format-specifiers

I have a short integer variable called s_int that holds value = 2

```
unsighed short s_int = 2;
```

I want to copy this number to a char array to the first and second position of a char array.

Let's say we have `char buffer[10];`. We want the two bytes of `s_int` to be copied at `buffer[0]` and `buffer[1]`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The usual way to do this would be with the bitwise operators to slice and dice it, a byte at a time:

```
b[0] = si & 0xff;
b[1] = (si >> 8) & 0xff;
```

though this should really be done into an `unsigned char`, not a plain `char` as they are signed on most systems.

Storing larger integers can be done in a similar way, or with a loop.

Comment: what's the reason for `& 0xff`?

Comment: It turns the implicit truncation into an explicit one. In other words, the programmer's intention is made clear. (I think some compilers might complain about it?)

Comment: How do I reconstruct the int from `b[0]` and `b[1]`?

Answer (score 7):

`*((short*)buffer)  = s_int;`

But *viator emptor* that the resulting byte order will vary with endianness.

Comment: gcc might tell you, `use of cast expressions as lvalues is deprecated`.

Comment: man, no way - think about the alignment. If buffer points to an odd index in the memory - let's *assume* address 0xFFF01 you are in big trouble.

Comment: @Iulian: I haven't heard of that restriction on x86, but of course it's fundamental to some other architectures.

Comment: @Iulian: this is not an issue on X86 (perhaps only on speed though...). However, this is important on other platforms such as IA64, MIPS, probably ARM and so on

Comment: @crazyscot and @botismarius I agree with your remarks but we're referring to C; we should try to be portable as much as possible.

Comment: Indeed, the deprecation warning I mentioned I saw on a msp430 platform, where memory alignment is an issue.  I wasn't able to generate this warning on my amd64 box.

Comment: John Ledbetter: That code doesn't use a cast expression as an lvalue; it uses the result of the unary `*` operator as an lvalue, which is fine (because it *is* an lvalue).  It does, however, still have the alignment problem.  ("Using a cast as an lvalue" is an expression like `(int)x = 10;`)

Answer (score 4):

I would memcpy it, something like

```
memcpy(buffer, &s_int, 2);
```

The endianness is preserved correctly so that if you cast buffer into unsigned short *, you can read the same value of s_int the right way. Other solution must be endian-aware or you could swap lsb and msb. And of course  sizeof(short) must be 2.

Comment: The `memcpy()` is a good approach, but note that "preserving the endianness" is not always correct.  crazyscot's answer puts the answer into the buffer with *known* endianness, which is often what is really needed (for example, if the buffer is to be saved to a file or sent across a network).  Your answer puts the answer into the buffer with *host* endianness, which is also sometimes what is needed (but less often).

Comment: yes of course: with "endiannes is preserved" I meant to say that the data are stored into buffer the same way a short is kept in memory, allowing direct accessing to the short value from buffer to, provided that the user does not need to change the endianness into something specific.

Comment: Though note that direct access to the short from the buffer is only possible if the buffer is correctly aligned for such access; in general if you are going to directly access it as a short you should have declared it as a `struct` containing a `short` member rather than as an array of `char`.

Comment: on processor that need alignment, and on processor that needs alignment to 2-byte, buffer is aligned too so it is ok to access it; x86 as far as I know does not require it (likely, accesses to not aligned memory is only slower).

Answer (score 3):

By using pointers and casts.

```
unsigned short s_int = 2;
unsigned char buffer[sizeof(unsigned short)];

// 1.
unsigned char * p_int = (unsigned char *)&s_int;
buffer[0] = p_int[0];
buffer[1] = p_int[1];

// 2.
memcpy(buffer, (unsigned char *)&s_int, sizeof(unsigned short));

// 3.
std::copy((unsigned char *)&s_int,
          ((unsigned char *)&s_int) + sizeof(unsigned short),
          buffer);

// 4.
unsigned short * p_buffer = (unsigned short *)(buffer); // May have alignment issues
*p_buffer = s_int;

// 5.
union Not_To_Use
{
  unsigned short s_int;
  unsigned char  buffer[2];
};

union Not_To_Use converter;
converter.s_int = s_int;
buffer[0] = converter.buffer[0];
buffer[1] = converter.buffer[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make all that bitwise stuff you could do the following

```
char* where = (char*)malloc(10);
short int a = 25232;
where[0] = *((char*)(&a) + 0);
where[1] = *((char*)(&a) + 1);
```