# Store a 2byte value in memory location in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, types, casting

I am in need of your help in this problem:

**I want to store a 2 byte number in a char array I have tried the below 2 logics but both have failed**

char buff[10];

char* ptr = buff;

/*
I want to store a 2 byte value say 750
Method 1 */

short a = 750;
*(++ptr)=a; //Did not work got these values in first 2 bytes in buffer: 0xffffffc8 0xffffffef

/* Method 2 */

short *a=750;
memcpy(++ptr,a,2) // Got segmentation fault

I know I can do this by dividing by 256 but I want to use a simpler method

*ptr++=750/256;

*ptr=750%256;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [copying a short int to a char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2952895/copying-a-short-int-to-a-char-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is simply:

```
uint16_t u16 = 12345;
memcpy(&buff[i], &u16, 2);
```

`memcpy` will place the data according to your [CPU endianess](https://software.codidact.com/posts/280640).

Alternatively you can bit shift, but since bit shifts themselves are endianess-independent, you need to manually pick the correct indices for `buff` according to endianess.

Memory layout like Little Endian:

```
buff[i]   = u16 & 0xFFu;
buff[i+1] = (u16 >> 8) & 0xFFu;
```

Memory layout like Big Endian:

```
buff[i]   = (u16 >> 8) & 0xFFu;
buff[i+1] = u16 & 0xFFu;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char buff[10];
short a=1023; 

//To store in char array
buff[0] = a & 0xff;
buff[1] = (a >> 8) & 0xff;

// To get original value.
short b = ((buff[1] << 8) & 0xff00) | (buff[0] & 0x00ff);
```

Comment: See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.